# How to add Drag and Drop File Upload with Livewire & Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I've got two issues with this code, first the file is uploaded twice when I drag and drop it. The console log shows two Filelist lines, (see screenshot) and in the livewire-tmp directory it adds two files. Second, the button that contains 'wire:click="removeFile"' isn't clickable anymore or atleast the click event isn't triggered. I know this because I've tried dd($file_name) within the Component that contains the removeFile method. If I remove the handleFilles function from the code, I can click to upload and the removeFiles button works.

```
<div x-data="{ focused: false, isDragging: false, files: [] }"
     @dragover.prevent="isDragging = true"
     @dragleave.prevent="isDragging = false"
     @drop.prevent="isDragging = false; handleFiles($event)"
     :class="isDragging ? 'border-indigo-600 bg-indigo-100' : 'border-gray-300'">

    <label :class="{ 'border-indigo-600 text-indigo-600': focused }" for="uploads"
           class="flex items-center justify-center w-full h-44 bg-gray-100 border-2 border-dashed
                   border-gray-200 text-gray-500 font-medium rounded cursor-pointer">
        <span x-text="isDragging ? 'Drop the files here...' : 'Drag & Drop your files here or click to upload'"></span>
    </label>

    <input @focus="focused = true" @blur="focused = false" type="file" id="uploads" multiple class="sr-only"
           wire:model.live="uploads">
</div>

<script>
    function handleFiles(event) {
        let uploadedFiles = event.dataTransfer.files;
        console.log(uploadedFiles);
        if (uploadedFiles.length > 0) {
            @this.uploadMultiple('files', uploadedFiles,
                (uploadedFilename) => {}, () => {}, (progress) => {
                    console.log(progress);
                }
            );
        }
    }
</script>

@if ($files)
    <ul>
        @foreach ($files as $file)
            <li>{{ $file->getClientOriginalName() }}</li>
            <button type="button" class="text-indigo-500" wire:click="removeFile('{{ $file->getFilename() }}')">
                Remove
            </button>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

[image]